# How can I let users register for a certain node type?

Tags: 7, forms

In Drupal 7.15, I use the Webforms module to allow guests to sign up to courses. I therefore created a content type *Registration Form*.

Courses themselves are individual content nodes, of the type *Course*.

Now, I'd like the user to be able to select a course to sign up for, and save that in the web form as well. How can I do that?

<sub>It seems that the [Webform Associate](http://drupal.org/project/webform_associate) module does exactly that:</sub>

> <sub>The Webform Associate module is designed to allow attaching webforms to particular node types. The example would be event registration. Event node types might need starting and ending dates, descriptions, etc. With Webform Associate a new webform node is automatically created, and the webform itself is appended to the bottom of the event node.</sub>

<sub>However it says that "Webform 3.0 Obsoletes this module and is not compatible in any way." Haven't found out how, though.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to associate the event using the [Node Registration](http://drupal.org/project/node_registration) module.

> Allows (authenticated and/or anonymous) users to register for events. Events are nodes with certain node types. You can enable registration for any node type and add fields and manage display per type and per node.

The module depends on [Value is](http://drupal.org/project/value_is) and [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) as well as [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools).

---

What you'll have to do after installation:

- Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/<course>/edit`, where `<course>` is your course
- Enable registrations at the bottom under *Registration Settings*
- Go to `admin/structure/node_registration/manage/<course>/fields` and add fields to your registration form, as required.
- Don't forget to enable the right permissions too for anonymous users.